# #REF! after refresh workbook

Tags: excel, vba

With some of my workbooks I get a `#REF!` error after updating my workbook.
I have to filter data to a worksheet Januari to filter Januari, and get a total sum in Sheet Total.

The code I have is working perfectly, but when I want to copy the total from column "C" to another worksheet I get a `#REF!` error.
Here is the line I get in my original sheet: `=SOM('WABO Oktober'!#VERW!)`, where is should be: `=SOM('WABO Oktober'!E:E)`
It does not happen in all the workbooks, just the one I need the most.

Here is a example of my code.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim Maand As String
    Maand = ActiveSheet.Name

    ' This is the name of the First part of the filtersheet
    Naam = ("filter") 

    ' Make sure sheet is visible
     Sheets((Naam) & " " & Maand).Visible = True
     Sheets(Maand).Select

    ' Range on active sheet
    Set My_Range = Range("A2:Y999")
        My_Range.Parent.Select

    'Remove AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' Select the columns you want to filter
    My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="y"

    'Copy/paste the visible data to the new worksheet
    Sheets((Naam) & " " & Maand).Select
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
        With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Select
    End With

    'AutoFit All Columns on Worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    'Close AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' Remove colums to create data filter Januari
    Range("A:A").Select
    Range("C1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    ' Got to cell A1
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

    'Go back to the  "Maand" Sheet
    Worksheets(Maand).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

    'Hide the filter Januari sheet
    Sheets((Naam) & " " & Maand).Visible = False

    'Refresh workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Comment: You are deleting cell `C1`. Apparently the formulas that refer to it become `#REF!`.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it.

Comment: You should avoid using `Select` and `Activate`.  Your code is short, but these will haunt you as you expand your work.

Comment: What can I use instead?

Comment: @Imans314 https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683

Comment: That iis VERY clear, thank you.